# Exception Error when I try to initialize hudson.war

Tags: exception, ubuntu, continuous-integration, hudson

I have installed hudson on Ubuntu server and then run java -jar hudson.war, giving me this exception error message:

> Status Code: 500  Exception: The error
>   below occurred during context
>   initialisation, so no further requests
>   can be processed:
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
>   at
>   java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
>   at
>   hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:257)
>   at
>   hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:112)
>   at
>   winstone.WebAppConfiguration.(WebAppConfiguration.java:889)
>   at
>   winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
>   at
>   winstone.HostConfiguration.(HostConfiguration.java:73)
>   at
>   winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
>   at
>   winstone.HostGroup.(HostGroup.java:45)
>   at
>   winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:196) 
>   at
>   winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:200)  Caused
>   by:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$InitializationException:
>   Could not instantiate converter :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter
>   : null     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:735)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:699)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:445)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:385)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:323)
>   at
>   hudson.util.XStream2.(XStream2.java:61)
>   at
>   hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:3571)
>   at
>   java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...11 more  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:728)
>   ...18 more  Caused by:
>   javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
>   at
>   javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter.(DurationConverter.java:33)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...19 more  Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
>   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.10) 
>   at
>   javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...21 more
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
>   at
>   java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
>   at
>   hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:257)
>   at
>   hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:112)
>   at
>   winstone.WebAppConfiguration.(WebAppConfiguration.java:889)
>   at
>   winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
>   at
>   winstone.HostConfiguration.(HostConfiguration.java:73)
>   at
>   winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
>   at
>   winstone.HostGroup.(HostGroup.java:45)
>   at
>   winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:196) 
>   at
>   winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:200)  Caused
>   by:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$InitializationException:
>   Could not instantiate converter :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter
>   : null     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:735)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:699)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:445)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:385)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:323)
>   at
>   hudson.util.XStream2.(XStream2.java:61)
>   at
>   hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:3571)
>   at
>   java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...11 more  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:728)
>   ...18 more  Caused by:
>   javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
>   at
>   javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter.(DurationConverter.java:33)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...19 more  Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
>   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.10) 
>   at
>   javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
>   ...21 more
>
> Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine
>   v0.9.10 at Mon Oct 25 14:55:59 PDT
>   20102010

Do you know what I am missing? 
any suggestions would be very appreciated.

regards 
Naoya

Comment: Make sure this isn't a file permission issue.

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks for your reply. yes that was I thought and I did it with sudo and still giving me the same error message. I can't figure it out what I am missing.. thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Is it the JRE or the JDK?

Comment: Perhaps you should get an instance of Apache Tomcat running and deploy Hudson on there. This is how I would recommend running and using Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

You probably run the wrong java. Check if you use <del>sun's</del> oracle's java.

See here for other people that had this problem:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1434376

Answer (score 0):

same comment, you probably have the wrong java version.
You can specify the correct path to the java binary in `/etc/default/hudson`.
If you use jenkins then edit `/etc/default/jenkins` instead.

```
# /etc/default/{hudson,jenkins}
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk_1.6
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar issue due to no more space in /tmp (root partition).