# InvocationTargetException while starting hudson on centOS

Tags: hudson, installation, centos

I installed Hudson using instructions given at http://hudson-ci.org/redhat/. When I ran the following command I got `InvocationTargetException`.

`root@host ~ # service hudson start`

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna9143314259601764116.tmp: /tmp/jna9143314259601764116.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

I am using Java's latest JDK... Any help?

Comment: A relevant link: http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hudson-installed-from-RPM-won-t-start-on-RHEL5-td1592057.html

Comment: The problem occurred when I didn't restart my machine after installing server. When I restarted, hudson daemon was running. So, I can now restart it.

Answer (score 6):

Realise this is an old question, but I stumbled across this looking for something else.

You cannot load a native library from inside a JAR file. Something is probably spitting out a bundled native library to /tmp/ before trying to load it from there. You have probably mounted /tmp/ with noexec, have a look in /etc/fstab:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid 0 0
```

It isn't a great idea, but you could remove the noexec from the mount.

Another (slightly better) way to fix this, provided the software doesn't depend on /tmp/ specifically, is to change the Java tmp dir:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/some/writable/directory
```

Comment: The noexec flag is really the culprit, too bad I didn't asked the question myself else I would have accept this answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a link that looks like a similar issue, with some things to try:

[Exception Error when I try to initialize hudson.war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027982/exception-error-when-i-try-to-initialize-hudson-war)